# Insert an Object inside an Array swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode

I'm getting an Object from API response which looks something like below.

```
"Home":[
{
"type":"Something",
"id":"Something",
"interval":3,
"category":"Something",
"title":"Something",
"vc":[]
},
{
"type":"Something",
"id":"Something",
"TableFooterDisclaimer":"",
"category":"Something",
"title":"Something",
"vc":[
{
"Something":"Something",
"id":0,
"Something":"Something",
"Something":"Something",
"Something":"Something",
"Something":"Something",
"Something":"Something",
},
{
"Something":"Something",
"id":1,
"Something":"Something",
"Something":"Something",
"Something":"Something",
"Something":"Something",
"Something":"Something",
},
{
"Something":"Something",
"id":2,
"Something":"Something",
"Something":"Something",
"Something":"Something",
"Something":"Something",
"Something":"Something",
}
]
},
```

I'm trying to insert one more record which looks like below.

```
let object : [String : Any] = [
"Something":"Something",
"id":1,
"Something":"Something",
"Something":"Something",
"Something":"Something",
"Something":"Something",
"Something":"Something",
]
```

This `object` I'm trying to insert inside `vc` array of the 1st index of `Home`, like below but getting issues.

```
if let serverArray = info["Home"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
     self.myArray = serverArray
     self.myArray![1]["vc"]?.insert(self.object, at: 0)
}
```

I have tried converting let object : [String:Any] to [String:AnyObject] but that also didn't work.

Comment: did you try [String : String]?

Comment: It won't be [String: String], I have just updated the snippets.

Comment: At which part do you have issue? `serverArray` has value and adding the object fails?

Comment: Have you considered creating a struct/structs and decode your data using Codable?

Comment: @gcharita Just asking, the way I'm trying to insert is correct ??

Comment: @JoakimDanielson: I haven't tried that.

Comment: Due to the value type behavior you have to modify `info` directly or eventually assign the modified value of "Home" back to `info`. The type `[String:AnyObject]` is pointless. Since Swift 3 a JSON dictionary is always `[String:Any]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
if var serverArray = info["Home"] as? [[String: Any]] {
    if serverArray.count > 1 {
        var vcs = serverArray[1]["vc"] as? [[String: Any]]
        vcs?.insert(self.object, at: 0)
        serverArray[1]["vc"] = vcs
    }
    self.myArray = serverArray
}
```

But it's a little ugly.

Using [Codable and JSONDecoder](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types) like @JoakimDanielson commented will be better.

Comment: I had to make some changes to the above solution but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Zac24 I am glad it worked. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)